# primeng chart how to set width 100%

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using Primeng 4.1 and would like to know how to set the width so the chart takes the full width of the row. When i set width="100%" , it is not working. Can anyone help how to set so that it is 100% width?

#### html

```
<div class="ui-g" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
  <p-panel header="Movement per case" class="ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad barChartPanel">
    <p-chart type="line" [data]="data" [options]="options" width="600" height="400"></p-chart>
  </p-panel>                            
</div>
```

#### js

```
this.options = {
    legend: {
        labels: {
            fontColor: 'white'
        }
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                color: '#373737'
            },
            ticks: {
                fontColor: '#fff'
            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                color: '#373737'
            },
            ticks: {
                fontColor: '#fff'
            }
        }]
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: false,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a stackblitz or anything to show what you are currently seeing? You could try adding `style="100% !important"` to your html tags until you find where it needs to be. you can also do this in dev tools in your browser.

```
<div class="ui-g" style="padding-bottom:10px; width: 100% !important">
  <p-panel header="Movement per case" class="ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad barChartPanel" style="width: 100% !important">
    <p-chart type="line" [data]="data" [options]="options" width="600" height="400"></p-chart>
  </p-panel>                            
</div>
```